# How to get client service custom fields value in the whmcs hook?

Tags: hook, whmcs

How do I get a client service custom Field value in whmcs hook?

I want to do something on AfterModuleCreate hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/module/#aftermodulecreate), the hook will receive the [module parameters](https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/module-parameters/):

```
add_hook('AfterModuleCreate', 1, function($vars) {

    $customFields = $vars['params']['customfields'];
    $fieldValue = $customFields['FieldName'];

});
```

Comment: Hello. I am trying to get the custom field value using `'chave' => $params['configoptions']["Chave"]`, but I am not getting it. Can you help me? See the image: https://prnt.sc/p04bdc

Comment: Did you try as in the answer above:
$customFields = $vars['params']['customfields'];
$chave = $customFields['Chave'];
Be careful with letters case,  $customFields['Chave'] is not the same as  $customFields['chave']

Comment: Can you tell me how do I get the value of the custom field, inside clientssummary.tpl?

Comment: https://whmcs.community/topic/302047-take-the-value-of-a-custom-field/?tab=comments#comment-1339825